# How to link multiple iTunes Clients to one Mediaserver

Tags: networking, shared-libraries, itunes

I have multiple Clients (older MacMinis with OSX Snow Leopart on it), which are in the same network with a Server (new MacMini with OSX Mountain). I would like to have them the same library, which worked well with the share for local network option.

But now I would like to run the [djay](http://www.algoriddim.com/djay-mac) app on it (to pitch the music), which only works with the local media as far as I know.

Is there a possibility to solve this problem? I thought about mounting the media folder on startup, and the symlink the data to the media folder, but users on the thin clients mustn't be allowed to change the data, so I'm not quite sure if it works.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler than I thought:

I just changed the media directory under Settings > Advanced to the servers media directory. This causes the djay app to also use that data, which works fine. There may be some strange effets if two persons alter the same playlist, but since now I dicovered no further problems.